# PDF and Excel generation problems when web application posted in Windows local server

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, pdf, iis

I posted my web application in windows server. It has the features like generating the PDF and Excel documents using HTTP context. The actual problem is the generated PDF document shows error as "File corrupted" and Excel document is getting copied with whole web page from which Excel document generates. But I am not facing the above problems when running my application in my local system. Here the below code for Excel generation .Please help me how to solve this

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = " ";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;            filename=Employee_Detail.xls;");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"2\" border=\"0\">");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<tr><td colspan=3 ><b><font size=6> Employee_Details</font></b></td></tr>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</table>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"2\" border=\"1\">");

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<tr>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td><b><font size=4> Name </font></b></td>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td><b><font size=4>Employee Id</font></b></td>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td><b><font size=4>Department</font></b></td>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</tr>");

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<tr>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>Ram</td>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>2200202029393020</td>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>Accounts</td>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</tr>");

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<tr>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>Jordan</td>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>2200202029393021</td>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>Sales</td>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</tr>");


    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<tr>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>Shyam</td>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>2200202029393022</td>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>Production</td>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</tr>");


    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<tr>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>Donald</td>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>2200202029393023</td>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<td>HR</td>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</tr>");

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</table>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your MIME types are not set up correctly in IIS ?

Have a look here: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: I assume .xls and not xsl? :)

Comment: yeah. sorry typing mistake.I meant it is .xls, but I didnt add MIME types newly in IIS . they already existed in it